# How to add Row Header in SWT table?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I want to add table row and column header for table. i have added column header but i don't understand how to add row header in RCP/SWT
.

Thanks and Regards 
 Rahul Nakate

Answer (score 1):

An SWT `Table` does not have the notion of a row header.

Look at this [SWT Snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet234.java) for inspiration on how to work around this.